# How to trace syntax errors in CREATE TABLE statements in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to run this script and for the life of me I can't get it working.. This is the information I was given to create the script, and my professor told me not to use INT, instead to use number or varchar. Still doesn't work.. Below that is the script I created, along with the error code. What am I doing wrong?

```
INV_NUMBER is an integer,               
LINE_NUMBER is an integer,              
P_CODE is a varchar with length 10              
LINE_UNITS is a number with length 9 and two digits after decimal point             
LINE_PRICE  is a number with length 9 and two digits after decimal point                


CREATE TABLE LINE (
INV_NUMBER int,
LINE_NUMBER int,
P_CODE VARCHAR (10),
LINE_UNITS NUMBER(9,2),
LINE_PRICE NUMBER(9,2),
);

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE LINE (
INV_NUMBER int,
LINE_NUMBER int,
P_CODE VARCHAR (10),
LINE_UNITS NUMBER(9,2),
LINE_PRICE NUMBER(9,2),
)
```

> Error report - ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: oracle is usually varchar2 isn't it?  VARCHAR is reserved by Oracle to support distinction between NULL and empty string in future, as ANSI standard prescribes. VARCHAR2 does not distinguish between a NULL and empty string, and never will. If you rely on empty string and NULL being the same thing, you should use VARCHAR2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformatting your code into a legible state makes the error far more clear:

```
CREATE TABLE LINE ( 
  INV_NUMBER int
  , LINE_NUMBER int
  , P_CODE VARCHAR (10)
  , LINE_UNITS NUMBER(9,2)
  , LINE_PRICE NUMBER(9,2)
  , 
);
```

That trailing comma is your problem. Remove it and your `CREATE` should work.

```
CREATE TABLE LINE ( 
  INV_NUMBER int
  , LINE_NUMBER int
  , P_CODE VARCHAR (10)
  , LINE_UNITS NUMBER(9,2)
  , LINE_PRICE NUMBER(9,2)
);
```

Comment: @cvelasquez1121 if that answered your question, please consider accepting the answer. It's the little check mark under the vote buttons :)

Comment: Did it! :) sorry I am a newb on this website. Enjoy your day!

Answer (score 0):

you have a comma at the end there.. 
also the professor told you to not use 'INT', but it looks like you're still using it... ? why?...

Comment: Yeah Idk.. but I removed it and added NUMBER. the question is, I don't know what to put inside the parenthesis. Unless I don't have to put anything at all?

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you'll never need to do math with it, and it's not a date, store it as varchar.  If you'll NEED to do math with it store it as a number.  If it's a date store it as a date.  Precision and scale of both number and varchar vary based on needs.